# What happens if you set a declared variable to a different type?

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = 4;
foo = "string"
```

What would happen here?

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: Nothing. The variable will have the new value.

Comment: `4` was accessible via `foo`. Now `"string"` is accessible via `foo`, but `4` is no more accessible.

Answer (score 4):

`foo` gets a new value, `"string"`. JavaScript is a loosely-typed language, variables (and object properties) are not restricted to only holding a single type of value during their lifecycle.

Gratuitous example:

```js
var foo = 42;
snippet.log(typeof foo); // "number"
foo = "The question of Life, the Universe, and Everything";
snippet.log(typeof foo); // "string"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lol, good answer + fine way to shamelessly plug the interesting version of console.log :D Have an upvote for both.

Comment: @nicael: LOL! Believe me, I would **love** to stop plugging it if they would just [fix the darned problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/). :-)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that question already, but didn't notice your answer somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

The type... changes. It's no more a number, but a string. JS is "type-fluid".

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have strict variable types. So no error is given; foo is just now equal to your string

Answer (score 0):

It will become the `string`. You can just check the data type of the variable like this

```
typeof(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JS does not care about the type. At least in fiddle.

Example :

```
var foo = 4;
alert(foo);
foo = "string";
alert(foo);
```

Runs perfectly.